# Why did Khabarov bury the cloth in the snow?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-way-back

In *The Way Back*, *Khabarov* buried some cloth in the snow in front of *Janusz*. *Janusz* even asked him why he is doing that. He replied: "you will see in the morning."

[image]

Next morning, *Janusz* removed the snow and checked the cloth, it filled with some *ants* or *insects*. *Janusz* has a smiling face after seeing this.

[image]

For what exact purpose did Khabarov bury the cloth in the snow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To get rid of lice

As detailed in this [review](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/01/21/movies/21way.html) of the film, Khabarov learns that burying your clothing in the snow should kill any lice.

---

This is further explained in this [wilderness survival guide](http://wildernessarena.com/environment/cold-weather-survival/cold-weather-survival):

> If you are using a previously used shelter, check your body and clothing for lice each night. If your clothing has become infested, use insecticide powder if you have any. Otherwise, hang your clothes in the cold, then beat and brush them. This will help get rid of the lice, but not the eggs.